# M3u radio streaming in android using eclipse

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, m3u

I am developing an Android radio streaming application.
I want to stream music using M#U file. Can you advise how can I achive this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are some previous questions that might help you with this

- [streaming .m3u audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688758/streaming-m3u-audio)
- [Using the Streaming media player](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)
- [Online radio streaming app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283568/online-radio-streaming-app-for-android)
- [Some bug in the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648758/streaming-from-m3u-on-android)